Who can diagnose and adjust automatic dampers?
I am trying to find the right person to diagnose and troubleshoot imbalanced zones and automatic dampers, but haven't been able to find anyone that seems experienced. Either the HVAC technicians seem focused on the furnace and blower or the sheet metal guys seem focused on making the ducts.
Which role is technically the right one to call, or is there a 3rd role that I don't know about?

Any HVAC tech worth his tools should do this no problem. You may be encountering resistance because the job isn't worth much--they have plenty of furnace replacements to keep them busy (and profitable). Keep trying until you find one who has capacity to help.
"Sheet metal guys" are just HVAC techs lower on the training ladder. They may not have the chops to configure electrical equipment. I've never encountered one who wasn't part of a larger HVAC shop, though, so I'm not sure where you have.

I'm in NYC, and the sheet metal guys have their own union and seem strictly separated from the HVAC guys for some reason.

Interesting. Do they install the dampers or just provide facilities for them? That's probably the key question.

I think they mostly do the ductwork only, bending and fitting sheet metal.  I'm still confused about the dampers, but I think that the sheet metal guys would fit the dampers... but maybe they don't wire them up?  Not sure.  https://www.smart28.org/who-we-are-video.html

I actually don't know what I'm talking about lol - just piecing together guesses based on what little people have told me.
